# How to add together numbers from a random number generator

Tags: java, eclipse

I am making a random number generator for school and I have to add the total all together, but the problem is I used a loop so I don't actually have the randomly generated numbers stored anywhere so I'm not quite sure what how to create a total. Like if the random number generator came out with 3 and 3 the total would tell you it was 6. Here's my code:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Assignment7 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random rand = new Random();
        
        int randomNumber = 0;
        
        System.out.println("Welcome to randomdiceroll.com or something!"
                         + "\nPlease enter how many dice you'd like to roll.");
        int amount = key.nextInt();
        
        System.out.println("Please enter the range for the di(c)e from 1-?");
        int limit = key.nextInt();
        
        for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
            randomNumber = rand.nextInt(limit) +1;
            System.out.println(randomNumber);
        }
        
        int total; //The part I cant figure out
        
        System.out.println("\nYour total is..." + total + ".");
        
        key.close();
    }
}
```

Excuse the horrible formatting, I've tried:

```
randomNumber * amount
```

But that obviously didn't work. I'm using Java If I explained this weird I can clarify for sure! I'm sure the answer is insanely simple but I am a beginner and sadly don't know.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Define the total before the for loop and add every time the random number to the total.
I would do it this way:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Assignment7 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random rand = new Random();
    System.out.println("Welcome to randomdiceroll.com or something!"
                         + "\nPlease enter how many dice you'd like to roll.");
    int amount = key.nextInt();
        
    System.out.println("Please enter the range for the di(c)e from 1-?");
    int limit = key.nextInt();
    int total = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
      randomNumber = rand.nextInt(limit) +1;
      total += randomNumber;
      System.out.println(randomNumber);
    }
    System.out.println("\nYour total is..." + total + ".");
    key.close()
  }
}
```

Comment: This works great! Thank you so much you were a big help!

Answer (score 0):

You could just add the random numbers inside the loop.

```java
int total=0;
for(int i=0; i<amount; i++){
    int randomNumber = rand.nextInt(limit) +1;
    total += randomNumber;
    System.out.println(randomNumber);
}
```